# Radius of Convergence with coefficient doesnt have a limit

Tags: power-series, dynamical-systems, irrational-numbers

I want to know when the series
$$ \sum _ { n = 1 } ^ \infty \frac { x ^ n } { \sin ( n \theta ) } $$
is convergent for $ \theta = t \pi $ such that $ t $ is irrational, e.g.  $ \theta = \sqrt 3 \pi $.

It is a really interesting question because it will tell something about how the $ \sin \left( \sqrt 3 \pi n \right)$ goes to zero for some sequence goes to infinity (since $ \sqrt 3 $ is irrational sin will have a dense image in $ [ 0 , 1 ] $).

Answer (score 0):

It converges when $x = 0$

$\lim_\limits{n\to\infty} \frac {x^n}{\sin n\theta}$ does not exist for $x\ne 0$

Comment: @Doug_M Can you show that it doesn't exist for $x<1$?